# How to nest mapped functions with the Earth Engine Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to extract data from multiple Images in an ImageCollection using multiple Features in a FeatureCollection. Because the Features are spread over a large geographical area, I can't supply the whole FeatureCollection to the `reduceRegions()` function without running out of memory. Instead it is easier to map over the FeatureCollection, and map the `reduceRegions()` function over the ImageCollection. Using flatten() at each map then results in a nice table for export to CSV. In JavaScript we can use anonymous functions, so it is relatively straightforward  to map a function within a mapped function as such:

```
var img1 = ee.Image(1);
var img2 = ee.Image(2);
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([img1, img2]);

function mapReducerOverImgCol(feat) {
  function imgReducer(img) {
    return img.reduceRegions({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
      collection: ee.FeatureCollection(feat),
      scale: 500,
      tileScale: 10
    });
  }
  
  return imgCol.map(imgReducer).flatten();
}

var table = featCol.map(mapReducerOverImgCol).flatten();

print(table);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b031ed7d8037181a4398c38b00dd16de

However, I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Python. Here is my failed attempt:

```
def nestedMappedReducer(featCol, imgCol):

    def imgReducer(img):
        return img.reduceRegions(
        collection = ee.FeatureCollection(feat),
        reducer = ee.Reducer.first(),
        scale = 500,
        tileScale = 10 
        )

    def mapReducerOverImgCol(imgCol):
        return imgCol.map(imgReducer).flatten()

    return featCol.map(mapReducerOverImgCol).flatten()
```

However this fails and complains that 'feat' is not defined.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in the Python code. The first is that it hasn't defined `feat` *at all.* In the JavaScript you have:

```
return featCol.map(function(feat){ ... }).flatten();
```

In the Python you have:

```
def mapReducerOverImgCol(imgCol): ...
return featCol.map(mapReducerOverImgCol).flatten()
```

You need to write `def mapReducerOverImgCol(feat):` to be equivalent to the JavaScript.

The second problem is that, like you nest functions in JavaScript, you must nest functions in Python, so that `feat` is in scope for the code in `imgReducer`:

```
def nestedMappedReducer(featCol, imgCol):
    def mapReducerOverImgCol(feat):
        def imgReducer(img):
            return img.reduceRegions(
                collection = ee.FeatureCollection(feat),
                reducer = ee.Reducer.first(),
                scale = 500,
                tileScale = 10 
            )

        return imgCol.map(imgReducer).flatten()

    return featCol.map(mapReducerOverImgCol).flatten()
```

Note that the functions being named rather than anonymous does not make a difference to this; here is your JavaScript converted to use named functions just like the Python:

```
function mapReducerOverImgCol(feat) {
  function imgReducer(img) {
    return img.reduceRegions({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
      collection: ee.FeatureCollection(feat),
      scale: 500,
      tileScale: 10
    });
  }
  
  return imgCol.map(imgReducer).flatten();
}

var table = featCol.map(mapReducerOverImgCol).flatten();
```