# Reduce many bands from image over many features from feature collection in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API retaining feature collection geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, multi-band, large-datasets, feature-collection

**The Situation**

I need to reduce by sum every band of an image with 40 bands (30x30m floats) over a global land covering grid of 10x10km (~4 Mio. features) and export the resulting table to Google Drive.

Context: I would like to get yearly tree cover loss area from Hansen (yearlyTreeCoverLossArea, 30x30m) and yearly emissions from Harris (yearlyEmissions, 30x30m) per covering grid cell (coveringGrid, 10x10km)

**What I tried**

- Option 1

I am mapping over the grid cells and reduce every band and return the summed up value within the grid cell of every band as an attirbute of the grid cell. The runtime for Ecuador only is around 4min. For the whole continent of South America it takes more than 8 hours (I did not let it finish).

```
yearlyTreeCoverLossArea = global extent 20 band image @ 30x30m
yearlyEmissions = global extent 20 band image @ 30x30m
coveringGrid = covering grid at 10x10m resolution

var multiband = yearlyTreeCoverLossArea.addBands(yearlyEmissions);

// Calculate yearly tree cover lost and total emissions per covering gridcell
var coveringGrid = coveringGrid.map(function (feature) {
  var multibandLUCSum =  ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), multibandLUC.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: feature.geometry(), 
    scale: 30,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels: 6e6
  }));
  // set attribute to feature
  return feature.set(multibandLUCSum.toDictionary());
});
```

- Option 2

Following [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365121/how-to-nest-mapped-functions-with-the-earth-engine-python-api) post I nest the grid cell and bands to leverage .map() twice. Surprisingly, for Ecuador this takes much longer than Option 1 (see above).

```
yearlyTreeCoverLossArea = global extent 20 band image @ 30x30m
yearlyEmissions = global extent 20 band image @ 30x30m
coveringGrid = covering grid at 10x10m resolution

var multiband = yearlyTreeCoverLossArea.addBands(yearlyEmissions);

// turn multiband image into image collection for mapping
var bands = multibandLUC.bandNames()
var list = bands.map(function(n) { return multibandLUC.select([n]) })
var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list)

function mapReducerOverImgCol(feature) {
  
  function imgReducer(img) {
    var multibandLUCSum =  ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), multibandLUC.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
      geometry: feature.geometry(), 
      scale: 30,
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      maxPixels: 3e6
    }));
  // set attribute to feature
  return feature.set(multibandLUCSum.toDictionary());
  }
  return imgCol.map(imgReducer).flatten();
}

var table = coveringGrid.map(mapReducerOverImgCol).flatten();
```

Note that I use reduceRegion() and not reduceRegions() to have control over maxPixels.

I also checked out [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246436/iterating-over-years-for-features-in-feature-collection-using-google-earth-engin) answer but did not understand how to potentially adapt it to my case.

**The Question**

How can I optimize the code above so I can run ~4 Mio. features of a 10x10km area over a 40-band 30x30m float image?